# Logical OR with a variable and a function definition as operands

Tags: javascript

I saw this line when I was reading a custom library created by a third party developers. What does this do in Javascript? Does it perform Logical OR on "modifier" and a return value from the function?

modifier = modifier || function( x ){ return x; };

Comment: `if (modifier) { modifier = modifier; } else { modifier = function(x) { return x; }; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
More in detail, it checks if `modifier` evaluates to `true`; in this case it assigns `modifier` value to `modifier` variable (noop); otherwise it assigns an anonymous function to `modifier`.

Comment: No - based on the question, he's asking if it's an OR of the RETURN value from the function.  It is OR'ed with the function itself.  While your explanation is correct, the answer's first line should be "No."  I would expand "it checks if modifier evaluates to true" to  "it checks if modifier evaluates to a truthy value (and a function definition evaluates to truthy so if modifier is already a function, it returns that function)"

Answer (score 1):

It returns `modifier`, if it has a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, like `function`. Otherwise it returns a function without calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In JavaScript, the || returns the left if it is a truthy value or the right if the left is a falsy value.

Effectively, if modifier is already a function, it will just leave it set.  If it is undefined or null, it will set a reference to the right side function.  It will not evaluate the function, however.

It would look like this if evaluated.

```
modifier = modifier || function( x ){ return x; }(); // notice the method invocation
```

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator is a lazy one. If it has the means necessary to compute it's value it doesn't evaluate the rest of the expression. The value of the logical operation `OR` is true when one of the parameters is true, so if `modifier` is considered to be a `true` value it will return itself and when not it returns the second parameter.

To see what is considered true in JS check [here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/).